# Option Release on Azure Devops is gone

Tags: azure-devops

Goodnight. I have a CI / CD process in Azure Devops that was working normally. As it is all set up, I, after completing a PR, simply execute a Build from my master branch. After successfully completing the Build, I generated a Release and deployed it.

But now I can no longer generate Release. The option to generate a release no longer appears in my pipelines and the message below appears:

**This build will be retained forever by master (Branch)**

I've already researched it in every way and I don't know what it can be. Has anyone experienced anything like this in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've already researched it in every way and I don't know what it can be. Has anyone experienced anything like this in Azure Devops?

Yes, I noticed that this message is in several regions for some my organizations, like Central US.

But I did not see this change in other regions, like East Asia. I think this should be a newly released change and it has not been applied to all regions. This small change is used to remind us how long the current pipeline will be retained.

If we manually retain the pipeline, the message will updated to the "This build will be retained forever by YouName (user)":

[image]

And for the option to generate a release, I have not seen it in the most recent versions, and it can be traced back to the TFS2018 version. I think this feature should be removed for a long time.

At present, when we create a release, we will select the release tab:

[image]

Comment: I speak from Brazil. These changes have also been applied in my region.
Anyway, your answer helped me and I managed to solve my problem.
I thank you for your help.